# Save file to Storage after Intervention encoding

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, intervention

I'm trying to save encoded by Intervention image to the specific storage

```
$converted_image = Image::make($req->file('image_file'));
$converted_image->resize(300, null, function ($constraint) {
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
});
$file=$converted_image->encode('png');
$path = Storage::putFileAs('images', $file->stream(), 'test.png');
```

returns an error:

```
Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream::getRealPath()
```

Another attempt with:

```
$path = Storage::putFileAs('images', $file->stream()->__toString(), 'test.png');
```

error:

```
Call to a member function getRealPath() on string
```

Any workaround to save file using Storage?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is `Storage::putFileAs()` requires either an `\Illuminate\Http\File` or `\Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile`, which is why it tries to call `getRealPath()` on it.

However, `Storage::put` does not and it will happily take a PSR-7 Stream. Try:

```
Storage::put('images/test.png', $file->stream());
```

Comment: @user947668 did this adequately answer your question?

Answer (score -1):

building on Dominic's answer:

you need an instance of File or UploadedFile.

For example:

```
Storage::putFileAs('images', new Illuminate\Http\File($file->stream()->__toString()), 'test.png');
```

Comment: why the downvote? this is a valid solutions (was at least at that time)